# Configuring cypress angular component testing

Tags: cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbfoB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynydf.png)
1 installed cypress 13.0.0
for angular component testing but am getting this error message
error displaying -- Error: Could not find angular.json. Looked in C:\Cypress-
do i need to add angular.json in my local folder

Comment: Please edit your question to include code and error messages as text.